# Text seems to disappear when reaches a certain size

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, genymotion

I have a small component and I seem to have an issue with the font size. When the fontSize is 179 the text loads correctly. When the font size is 180 and above it seems to vanish.

```
return (<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
<Text numberOfLines={1} style={{
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    fontSize: 179,
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    color:'rgba(0,0,0,.3)',    
    flex: 1, 
    flexWrap: 'wrap', 
}}>A</Text>
</View>);
```

I can still see the element in dev tools:

[image]

Has anybody come across this before?

Am I just missing something?

Thanks, James

Comment: What exactly is your goal with this text?

Comment: @FunkSoulNinja the first goal is just to get the font size correct really. I'm not too fussed about the position. I have removed the styles and all other attr apart from fontSize and I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: I see. Do you need such a big font size? The default font size is about 14.

Comment: @FunkSoulNinja yeah for this current project I do. I didn't think this would be a hurdle to cross when I started. I assumed the fontSize would just work.

Comment: What part of the text is being cut off? Are you sure that any parent views aren't cutting it off? Try giving a background color to the text or its parent components to see if the text is not getting squished in any way.

Comment: @FunkSoulNinja All of it get's cut off. I have now stripped the app back to just a <View> and <Text> and I still get the same issue. This is using the starter app from react-native. This is a very odd issue, could it be the emulator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172622/discussion-between-funk-soul-ninja-and-james-dale).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have numberOfLines={1} and flexWrap together; They contradict each other.
If you want it the text to wrap around, remove numberOfLines or have it be more than 1.

If you don't want text to wrap remove flex and flexWrap properties from the style object.

What is your goal with those styles? I recommend you start with unstyled (default) styled . Add styles one by one and see what works or doesn't work to give you your desired results.